# How to set up htaccess for static html multilingual website with the default language files inside root folder and another language in a subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess

A client recently decided to add a second language to the static html website I created for them, so I need some help with setting up .htaccess file in order to automatically redirect users whose browser language is set to German to subfolder /de/ while every other browser language should default to root folder.

I searched for a solution for a while now but they all seem to be predicated on every language having it's own separate subfolder, including the default language, for example like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# language starts with DE
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]

# else redirect to the English version
RewriteRule ^$ /en/ [L,R=301]
```

My client wants only users whose browser language is set to German to be directed to a subfolder on the domain. He doesn't want english language users to be directed to /en/ so I have to have the english language html files inside the root folder.
I'm trying to set this up on localhost before deploying it and whenever I try to redirect to root folder for the english language I get an error in the browser.

```
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself. In order to have the default language files in the root folder you just have to add redirect for languages other than the default.
In my case I just had to add this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^de [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/ [L,R=301]
```